# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. plz help me out plz

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-errors

I'm trying to connect a form with the database but I encounter this error any expert plz help

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.conf import settings
   # Create your views here.
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    username = request.POST['username']
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['pass']
    cnfrm_password = request.POST['cnfrm_password']
    phone_number = request.POST['phone_number']
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name, phone_number=phone_number)
    user.save()
    print('user created')
    return redirect('/')
   else:
   return render(request, 'register.html')
```

Comment: could you provide the error message or which line that error?

Comment: @dhentris the error is the one mentioned in the title.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and you should (re-)read the help topic [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to set your expectations. Your question title should contain a question. Post the whole error message in a readable format inside your question body.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you didn't define `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` which results in undefined settings. `INSTALLED_APPS` at this point is the first setting that Django wants to look up, resulting in the given error.

With a default project creation the created `manage.py` defines said environment variable and if you run `python manage.py runserver` the settings are defined.

Also see the according [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-and-manage-py).

However since with your setup these settings aren't defined: Set an environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` pointing to your `settings.py`. Also see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings) for this.